# Emulating materialized views in PostgreSQL with concurrent refreshes

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, materialized-views

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.2.4 and would like to emulate a materialized view. Are there any well-known methods for doing this, including concurrent refreshes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PostgreSQL wiki - materialized views](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Materialized_Views) links to two trigger-based implementations.

The general idea is to put `AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ... FOR EACH ROW` triggers on each involved table that do partial updates on the target table. Implementation is fairly specific to the nature of the view.

For some more complex views you can't really do partial updates and need to do a concurrent view refresh instead. That usually involves creating a new table, populating it, committing, beginning a new transaction, dropping the old table, renaming the new one to the name of the old one, and committing again.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from 9.5, Postgres supports **Concurrent Refresh** as stated [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html) in the official documentation. However, there are two preconditions that needs to be satisfied to do so:

1. You must create an unique index on the materialized view
2. The unique index must include all the records of the materialized view. In other words you cannot have a `WHERE` clause in your create index command.

The command to refresh the materialized concurrently view is following:

```
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY *mat_view_name*;
```

Note that refreshing the materialized view concurrently is relatively slower than the normal refresh. However, it will make sure that none of your queries on the materialized view is blocked during the concurrent refresh.